# What is the correct way to reference items in multi-dimensional lists?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-3.x

I am attempting to write a command line minesweeper clone, and I am having some trouble with the mine generator code.

```
def genWorld(size, mines):
    world = []
    currBlock = []
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            currBlock.append("x")
        world.append(currBlock)
        currBlock = []
    for i in range(mines):
        while True:
            row = randint(0, size)
            col = randint(0, size)
            if world[row[col]] != "M":
                break
        world[row[col]] = "M"
    printWorld(world)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\minesweeper.py", line 28, in <module>
    genWorld(9, 10)
  File "C:\Python33\minesweeper.py", line 23, in genWorld
    if world[row[col]] != "M":
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I'd imagine this means that I am referencing the list in the wrong way, but how would I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: You could create `world` by doing something like: `world = ['x' for _ in xrange(size)] for _ in xrange(size)]`, and get locations of mines with something like: `import random; loc = random.sample(xrange(size*size), mines); for i in locations: world[i/size][i%size]='M'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give `row` an integer value.  `row[col]` then tries to access an element of that integer, which gives an error.  I think what you want is `world[row][col]`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `world[row][col]`, as `world[row]` gives a list, then `[col]` selects an element from that list.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a dict instead of nested arrays:

```
# positions for mines
mines = set()
while len(mines) != mines:
    pos = (randint(0, size), randint(0, size))
    if not pos in mines:
        mines.add(pos)

# initialize world
world = {}
for x in range(size):
    for y in range(size):
        if (x, y) in mines:
            world[x, y] = 'M'
        else:
            world[x, y] = ' '
```

You could also use dict's get() function, which will return `None` if there is no mine, but then you could as well stay with the set (`if pos in mines: booom()`) to keep things easy.